On distribution of prime pairs from polynomials
Consider the polynomials
$g(x)=(2x)^4+((2x)^2+1)^2$
$h(x)=(2x)^4+((2x)^2−1)^2$
If $k$ is odd integers, $x_1,\dots,x_k$ are uniformly randomly chosen in $(t,2t)$, and the polynomials are evaluated at these integers, what is the expected number of integers at which both polynomials would evaluate to primes?

See Bateman-Horn conjecture for the conjectural answer. Don't expect much unconditionally - we don't even know if there are infinitely many x at which one of these polynomials is prime, let alone both at once.
